# Arugment is missing, with no default

Tags: r

Ive tried to locate the mistake causing the error, had no luck. The full error given by R is :
Error in updateBatsman("run0", playerA) :
argument "ln" is missing, with no default
Not sure what to do. Any help is appreciated.

```
  initialisePlayer <- function(name){
  list_data <- list(name, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  }

  playerScoreBoard <- function(ln, header){
  print(noquote(format(c("Name", "0s", "1s", "2s", "3s", 
  "5s", "X", "Out", "Tot"))))
  print(noquote(format(c(ln[1], ln[2], ln[3], ln[4], ln[5], 
  ln[6], ln[7],ln[8], as.numeric(ln[3])+ 
  (2*as.numeric(ln[4])) + (3*as.numeric(ln[5])) + 
  (5*as.numeric(ln[6])) ))))
```

}

```
 playerA <- initialisePlayer("T Smith") 
 playerB <- initialisePlayer("N Starc")
 playerScoreBoard(playerA, header = TRUE)
 playerScoreBoard(playerB)

 updateBatsman <- function(ballOutcomes,playerScoreBoard, 
 ln){
 if ("run0" == ballOutcomes ){
 list_data[2] <- as.numeric(ln[2]) +1
 } else if ("run1" == ballOutcomes ){
 list_data[3] <- as.numeric(ln[3]) +1
 } else if ("run2" == ballOutcomes ){
 list_data[4] <- as.numeric(ln[4]) +1
 } else if ("run3" == ballOutcomes ){
 list_data[5] <- as.numeric(ln[5]) +1
 } else if ("run5" == ballOutcomes ){
 list_data[6] <- as.numeric(ln[6]) +1
 } else if ("out" == ballOutcomes ){
 list_data[8] <- as.numeric(ln[8]) +1
 } 
 return(list_data) 
 }

 updateBowler <- function(ballOutcomes,playerScoreBoard,ln) 
{

if ("illegal" == ballOutcomes ){
list_data[7] <- as.numeric(ln[7])+1
} 
return(list_data)
}

ballOutcomes <- c("run0", "run1", "run2", "run3", "run5", 
"illegal", "out")


playerScoreBoard(updateBatsman("run0", playerA), header = 
TRUE)
playerScoreBoard(updateBatsman("run1", playerA))
playerScoreBoard(updateBatsman("out", playerA))
playerScoreBoard(updateBatsman("illegal", playerA))
playerScoreBoard(updateBowler("run0", playerA))
playerScoreBoard(updateBowler("run5", playerA))
playerScoreBoard(updateBowler("illegal", playerA))
```

Comment: `updateBatsman` has three required input arguments (`ballOutcomes`, `playerScoreBoard`, `ln`), but you are only providing the first two in your later calls.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the updateBatsman function as `updateBatsman <- function(ballOutcomes,playerScoreBoard,ln){...}` with the arguments ballOutcome, playerScoreBoard and ln.

Later you call it with `updateBatsman("run0", playerA)`, which has only two arguments.

Either you just forgot to add the `ln` in the last lines of your code or, if the ln is not always necessary, add a default in the function definition. That could look like this:

```r
updateBatsman <- function(ballOutcomes, playerScoreBoard, ln = c(1:8){
 ...
}
```

Addition: I don't know what you ln is supposed to be, so you'd have to define the default value in a fitting way.

Comment: oh okay, that makes sense. I've added it and work it perfectly now. Thanks very much.

Comment: Always happy to help. Don't forget to mark your question as solved :)